# PHP magic __call in parent's parent being called instead of method in abstract parent

Tags: php, multiple-inheritance, magic-methods

I'm trying to setup a VM of some working production code. The production server is running php 5.5 and the local vm 5.4.

I have three classes

```
class SysEvt extends AbstractRepository
{
    public function foo(){
       $this->persist();
    }
}
```

it's parent class

```
abstract class AbstractRepository extends EntityRepository 
{
    public function persist(){
        //not being called
    }
}
```

and the parents's parent.

```
class EntityRepository implements ObjectRepository, Selectable 
{
    public function __call(){
        // error if persist is called
    }
}
```

and the __call method is generating an error. I've checked the changelog for php 5.5 and I don't see any change that could be causing this.

What could be causing this error?

Comment: _"the __call method is generating an error"_ which error?

Comment: the _call method throws an Exception if called with 'persist'

Answer (score 0):

This was a caching issue. Doesn't happen in normal PHP execution.